# Not able to login to docker lab server using putty

Tags: docker, unix, ssh

I was trying to login to a docker lab host using Putty but not able to login. The error is :-
**'no authentication method available server sent public key'.**

If I pass both **username@server** name i get error.

If I only pass the server name i get to the login screen but then when i enter my username the error pops up 
I tried searching the web but couldn't find.

Please can anyone help me.

Comment: Can you post the actual command you're running?  How (if at all) is Docker involved?  Have you asked the administrator of the system you're trying to log into for assistance?

Comment: actually i have logged into labs.play-with-docker.com and launch a server. There is option of connecting the machine from outside using ssh.The have given the username and server name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can refer to the article "[PWD + SSH = ❤](https://medium.com/@marcosnils/pwd-ssh-c12080ea11d1)" (with "PWD" = "Play With Docker").

The full command should be:

```
 ssh -p 1022 <instance_ip_with_dashes>-<short_session_id>@pwdhost
```

But that requires on the client side to have in $HOME/.ssh

- id_rsa: the private key
- id_rsa.pub: the public key registered in `<instance_ip_with_dashes>-<short_session_id>` home.

Since copying a private key is not a good practice, you can do the opposite (in a Git bash session, not using putty):

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Copy the *public* generated key to `~<instance_ip_with_dashes>-<short_session_id>/.ssh/authorized_keys`

*Then* your SSH session will be possible.

---

Note: All that is managed for you if you are using the [docker-machine pwd driver](https://github.com/play-with-docker/docker-machine-driver-pwd), as shown in the article above:

[image: https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1000/1*sxDjq62_bV5rCjPOEbACaQ.gif]

As you can see, in that case, a `docker-machine ssh` is enough.

Comment: Thnx for the help. I'll check and let you know.

Comment: Actually I'm using putty to connect to the server as I'm on windows so could please help how do i connect as i read the article and i want to connect without using driver.So in putty where should i put the port no 1022.And on the server 1022 port is not in listening state

Comment: @sandy560 First, don't use putty key, those are Windows SSH keys. Use a regular open ssh, and a regular bash (like the one coming with Git for Windows: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases). Make sure to get the SSH public and private keys from your PWD machine back to  your local `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh` folder. And the port is set as shown in the answer.

Comment: I'm not using any windows key.I'm just using putty to ssh.So do i have to specify private key for ssh.

Comment: @sandy560 Exactly: to connect to a remote machine in SSH, you need to have locally the private key and public key, stored as I mentioned. Without using putty. Just a bash (if you install Git, you get both a bash and openssh)

Comment: Tried with git and added  copied the private key from the server and paste into a file in .ssh folder of my client(windows machine) but when i'm trying to do ssh with port number the screen is blank but when i tried without port number it is asking for paraphrase and the permission denied (paraphrase is set to empty).

Comment: @sandy560 while the screen might be blank, can you still type `hostname` and `id -a`, to check if you have connected?

Comment: Vonc. Thnx for your time mate. I have also opened a thread on github https://github.com/play-with-docker/play-with-docker/issues/285 .Let see if I can get any help from the team.

Answer (score 0):

http://github.com/play-with-docker/play-with-docker/issues/285
 Actually I had to create or generate keys on the client. In order to start the communication between the client and the server.But I was copying the private key of the server silly me.

Key generation  can be done in 2 ways 
1. If you are using git run ssh-keygen
2. If you want to login using putty the first generate keys using puttygen and then attached the private key .ppk while ssh.